# Oracle DB - can it run without JDK, JRE that is installed together with?

Tags: oracle, java, oracle-19c

Our client is scanning for outdated JDKs or JREs and found those in Oracle DB instance files, installed files.

Is it safe for Oracle DB to remove JDK, JRE?

```
Name="Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment" Version="1.8.0_371"
Value="/opt/oracle/product/19.20.0.0.230718/jdk/bin"

Name="Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment" Version="1.8.0_371"
Value="/opt/oracle/product/19.20.0.0.230718/jdk/jre/bin"

Name="Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment" Version="1.8.0_381"
Value="/opt/oracle/product/19.20.0.0.230718/OPatch/jre/bin"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database may be able to run without it, but tools such as `opatch`, `orapki` use that Java, I would not remove it.

`1.8.0_371` and `1.8.0_381` were released in April 2023 and July 2023, they are not outdated.

JDK 8 is the supported version for 19c and 21c. Oracle Database 23c is delivered with JDK 11.

Comment: Oracle provides specific patching instructions to update those embedded JDKs as part of normal patching procedures. They do not support removal.